# Proxy server/setup on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, proxy

I need to setup proxy on one system and allow all user to use Internet via the machine on which proxy is installed.

I have searched internet and there is Squid, but I need to configure this, which I dont know.

I have address from 192.168.5.100 to 192.168.5.150
I need to add this all adress to proxy and all machine should use proxy settings for internet.

Looking for some good solution.

Gopal

Answer (score 0):

Squid is a opensource tool which work as a proxy for clients. You need to install it on your server and you need to configure some recommended settings to make it start and working.

Please refer [Squid configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid) for sample configuration and make it working. It is very simple to set and make it working.

There are some basic configuration parameters which you need to set like your source network. To use squid for your any specific requirement you can use 'acl' (squid configuration parameter) which will allow you to set rules for any specific requirement.

One more Ref: [Squid installation and configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html)

Comment: Hi,thanks, for help, I have installed squid from same link only, but I cant configure as per my need. or I dont know how to configure. Please help me in some easy method.

Comment: What is your need? Are you using it in corporate network or for personal use?

Comment: my need is to setup proxy between 20 -30 users. its not corporate, its for internal purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

A simple configuration of Squid only needs the modification of this lines:

a) A visible hostname.

This is the hostname found in the file `/etc/hosts.`

```
visible_hostname yourcomputer
```

b) An acl for the your local network.

This is the src that indicates the source of the network.

```
acl my-network src 10.148.13.0/255.255.255.0
```

c) A http_access

This is a variable that will allow users on the internal network to access the internet, it must match the acl name for the your local network that you use.

```
http_access allow my-network
```

Save your configuration changes.

and you need to create the cache for the proxy server

```
sudo -i
squid -z
```